# spring boot upload file allow only images

Tags: spring, spring-boot, file-upload, image-uploading

```
@Controller
public class UploadController {

    @PostMapping("/upload") 
    public String upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        // save
    }
}
```

How to specify/config that only images(jpeg, png) are allowed to be uploaded?

Answer (score 1):

You should do a check on `file.getContentType()` if it matches "image/jpeg" or "image/png". Not sure if consumes property of the `@PostMapping` would work because the request is of type "multipart/form-data" or "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" it seems.